# Extra 'b' preceeding the actual output in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, canopy

So, I am new to TensorFlow and will be just starting to learn it. I installed TensorFlow on the IDE Canopy using 'pip' command.

While confirming if it had been installed correctly, I entered the following code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

This should have given an output :

```
Hello, TensorFlow!
```

Instead I get an extra letter 'b', preceeding this, like :

```
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

Is this a problem to be sorted or is it fine and would be ok if I don't do anything about this ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'b' indicates that it is a bytestring (rather a sequence of octets). Use decode() to get the string.

```
print(sess.run(hello).decode())
```